# Can the "Name" attribute on a WCF ServiceContract be used to change the service's URI?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

So the "Name" attribute in a DataContract's DataMember can be used to control the resulting serialized json:

```
[DataContract(Name = "AuthenticationContract")]
public class AuthenticationContract
{
    [DataMember(Name = "first_name")]
    public string FirstName;

    [DataMember(Name = "last_name")]
    public string LastName;

}
```

results in:

```
{"first_name":"frank","last_name":"rizzo"}
```

I was hoping that the Name attribute on a ServiceContract would do something similar:

```
[ServiceContract(Name="nameapi")]
public class NameAuthenticationService : INameAuthenticationService    
{
    [OperationContract]
    public string GetName()....
}
```

So that instead of this

```
http://localhost:49531/NameAuthenticationService/GetName
```

... I could use this

```
http://localhost:49531/nameapi/GetName
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, ServiceContractAttribute.Name controls the `<portType>` exposed by the WSDL you publish from the service. What you want to do is change the base address of the service, which you should be able to set in the service's .config file (or set it manually if you're self-hosting). See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788982(v=VS.85).aspx